# construct URL query string: character set encode/decode

Tags: java, jsp, character-encoding

I'm trying to construct an URL with query string containing *other* characters (hebrew in my case).
However, when my webapp receives the request, the extracted request parameters are gibrish...

How can I resolve this?

```
new URL("http://localhost:8080/SRV/page.jsp?param=" + URLEncoder.encode("heb text", "UTF-8")).openConnection();
```

target page:

```
<%
    System.out.println("Receive: " + request.getParameter("param"));
%>
```

I'm using tomcat6, jdk6, windows7 x64

edit: this is my page declaration:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Comment: Does yout JSP use a UTF-8 charset?

Comment: Welcome to SO. As suggested by Le Guen try adding <%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%> to your jsp and output the param in the web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml` file and check the encoding setting:

```
<Connector port="8080" ... URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

It appears that Tomcat needs this setting for UTF-8 to work for HTTP request values, such as request parameters.